# Twig Cache Error

Tags: php, twig

I'm getting a Twig error ...

*Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write in the cache directory (./cache/twig/69).*

but only ever in that 1 hexadecimal directory listed above. If I then set the permissions on that folder to 0777 and also set the permissions on the files it contains, it works correctly but only for a few days. I then have to do the same fix and so on and so on. None of the other directories in the twig folder are affected. Any ideas?

Comment: Well after putting up with this for so long I updated the phpBB forums from 3.1 to 3.2 and still get this issue but now in a different folder ...


PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to write in the cache directory (./cache/production/twig/8b)

However it is changing the owner to 'root' from 'www' and my moderator then cannot access the script referenced in the above folder until I change the owner back to 'www'. Is there some kind of twig log which would help me here ?

Comment: Something is running the application as root. Maybe a cronjob that's in root's crontab or some admin doing "php bin/console" commands as root?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the permission of the folder. It should have write access.
2. Check SELinux policy

   sestatus
3. To disable SELinux

   sudo setenforce 0

Answer (score -1):

Are you running commands from the CLI with a different user than the webserver? This often occurs if you run console commands as e.g. root and they create cache directories. Try clearing the cache completely after each CLI call.

Comment: No I'm not running any commands from the CLI. I always login as root anyway as this is a dedicated server and there are no users outside of root. I should really have mentioned also that Twig is running as part of phpBB 3.1 but support regarding this was non-existent.

Comment: Then what are owner and group of the cache directory and its subdirectories? Do they match? Maybe you need to `chown`/`chgrp` the cache directory so phpBB can always write and create new directories there.
This is most likely a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is a permissions issue. I've just noticed that some files / folders in the 'cache' folder had the owner set to 'www' and some to 'root'. I've now forced all files and folders to have the owner of 'root', which includes the 'twig' folder. Will now wait and see if this fixes the issue.